# What type of neutrinos do we detect

Tags: standard-model, neutrinos

There are three types of neutrinos known today. When detecting them, how can we tell which type we are detecting?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neutrino flavor is defined as agreeing with the flavor of the charged lepton participating in the interaction, so that the neutrino in the reaction
$$ \nu + A \to \mu + X \,, $$
is defined to be a muon neutrino and the one in
$$ \nu + n \to e + p $$
is a electron neutrino by definition.

We have no way of knowing the alleged flavor of a neutrino participating in a neutral current interaction.

---

As a matter of experimental fact electron and moun neutrinos (and anti-neutrinos) are easy, but tau neutrinos are much harder because demonstrating that you have a tau-lepton is hard, but both OPERA and IceCube can do that (to chose currently running experiments).

Comment: Polite cough: this answer doesn't actually say _how_ we tell which type of neutrino we're detecting.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: Yes it does. If a muon suddenly appears "from nowhere", then a muon neutrino must have been there.  Likewise for eletrons.